# What does "No receivers detected" mean for Configuration Link Status?

Tags: phy, pci

I'm trying to bringup PCIe, and stuck when trying to link up. Configuration Link Status is `00`, which means "No receivers detected", as this document says https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/pg213-pcie4-ultrascale-plus/Configuration-Status-Interface

If it link up successfully, the Link Status should be "11b: Link up, DL initialization completed" instead.

Two questions:

1. what's the receiver?
2. When will the Link Status become "No receivers detected"?

Comment: I think this question is best answered by the experts at Xilinx technical support. Just create an account if you don't already have one and log-in to post your questions etc ... good luck.

Comment: Thanks, will try